# Is it possible to query JSON data stored in Android SQLite database

Tags: android, json, xpath

Is it possible to query JSON data stored in Android SQLite database. Like for e.g. I can store `xml` data in [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) and query it using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath), is something similar possible in [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite)?

Comment: You can store BLOB or TEXT into SQLite, then just retrieve that and query it. Or could use [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#json) to just store/read JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the answer that you were looking for?

```
{
    ContentValues value= new ContentValues();
    value.put("Key", "Value");
    Global.dbw.insert("Table Name", value);
}

public long insert(String tablename, ContentValues values) 
{
   long result = db.insert(tablename, null, values);
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you say the answer is no. You can search using "LIKE" in **SQLite**, but can be very slow.

The best way is parse this json into classes and store db data into tables.

If you need only few keys in the json, create a "MetaClass" (if i can call it that) and parse only the fields you want to search. Eg.:

JSON:

```
{"name": "Mateus", "age": 23, "extra_data": "blbablalbalbalbalbalblbalbalbla"}
```

Class:

```
class User{
 String name;
 int age;
 String fullJsonData;
}
```

Then you have all JSON data sotred in a column and de "query" data into columns.

---

This can helps you a lot!
[JsonSchema2POJO](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

It "converts" your JSON to an Java Class using the parser you want. I like to use the Jackson.

Comment: Sad to hear this. :(